# How to stop #DIV/0 from appearing in your cells content

Tags: excel

I want to stop this from showing up... Maybe its an old question but I haven't been able to find the answer...

[image]

Comment: http://www.xlninja.com/2012/08/24/how-to-hide-the-div0-error-message-in-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your formula from:

```
=A1/B1
```

to:

```
=IFERROR(A1/B1,"")
```

Adapt this to all your formulas containing division.